# Data-request: should an answer contain only one data set, or should I concatenate all the data sets in a single answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Assume a question is a data request. I am aware of a few one data sets satisfying the request requirement: should I write one answer per data set, or should I concatenate all the data sets in a single answer?

On https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ it's one tool per answer, and it seems to work great (people can vote and comment on a specific tool this way, it's cleaner), so I'd tend to write one answer per data set, but just to know whether there exists any established policy on that matter.

Answer (score 2):

*My preferences...*

If the answers are just different links, with small descriptions, then I usually combine them.

But if the answers are wildly different, with big explanations, than I post them separately.

Some examples of multi-post answers:

- [Large French dataset for NLP (not formal, rather discussions/reviews)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1801/1511)
- [Obtaining personal mail corpus](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4517/1511)
- [Free English Dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4341/1511)

Example of single-answer post (now a community wiki)

- [What are some OpenData torrents to seed?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4080/1511)